# What is the best way to create a NuGet package for a Windows UWP library?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, nuget

I have several projects that share the same UWP controls.  I want to package them up the same way I package my .NET Standard libraries (where the packaging is integrated into the IDE).  What is the best way to do this with Visual Studio 2019 that doesn't involve distributing a copy of nuget.exe?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If the issue persists to block you, could you share some details about your project structure in VS solution explorer and your xx.nuspec file, so that I can try to reproduce your issue and check for you. And if you've found the workaround yourself, you can share it as answer to help members with similar issue. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to package them up the same way I package my .NET Standard
>   libraries (where the packaging is integrated into the IDE).

For now, only the new SDK-format projects(`.net core and .net standard`) have the quick `right-click project=>pack` option.

This same behavior(right click=>pack button) for now is not available for UWP library projects.

> What is the best way to do this with Visual Studio 2019 that doesn't
>   involve distributing a copy of nuget.exe?

One alternative way is to use `Nuget.Build.Tasks.Pack` package.

**Step1:** Consume the package with available latest version.

**Step2:** In VS `right-click project=>Unload the project=>Edit the xxx.csprj`(also we can modify the xx.csproj in file system) to add this script into `<Project>` tag:

```
<Project xxx>
  ......

  <!--This custom PropertyGroup will be used to specify the package.-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>packageName</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.2.2</PackageVersion>
    <PackageOutputPath>$(Outputpath)</PackageOutputPath>
    <Authors>unknown</Authors>

    <!--<Title></Title>
    <Description></Description>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <RequireLicenseAcceptance></RequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <LicenseUrl></LicenseUrl>
    <ProjectUrl></ProjectUrl>
    <IconUrl></IconUrl>
    <ReleaseNotes></ReleaseNotes>
    <Tags></Tags>
    <PackageTypes></PackageTypes>
    ...
    <NuspecFile></NuspecFile>-->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

We can specify the package's `ID,version,authors,outputpath`(required) in that `PropertyGroup`, also if necessary we can set many other elements like `Description, Title, ReleaseNotes, NuspecFile...` there.

**Step3:** Now we can open [Developer Command Prompt for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to run `msbuild /t:pack ...` to pack that project using command-line.

Or we can add `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` to that PropertyGroup, then if we build in VS(right-click project=>build or build solution), VS will automatically package that library during build process.

More info about this topic please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild#add-the-nugetbuildtaskspack-package), hope it helps to resolve your issue:)

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but incomplete.  None of my resources (bitmaps, themes, XAML) can be found when I try to consume my newly created package.  I suspect there are some additional settings, but I can't find any references.

Comment: `Could not copy the file "C:\Users\Fred\.nuget\packages\thetarex.forms\1.0.4\lib\uap10.0.17763\Forms\Assets\View.png" because it was not found.`  Getting this error with the above suggestion.

Comment: If you want to include the resources into package, please check these two documents([one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages#adding-xaml-content) and [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-ui-controls#add-design-time-support)). These two documents all indicate that you need to include them by defining xx.nuspec file... Hope it helps.

Comment: I could not find `<NuspecFile>` attribute inside `PropertyGroup`, Did you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is our doc page about building UWP controls in the NuGet documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages

Please make sure to check it out, and suggest any improvements to that page as well.

Comment: Yes.  I found that page earlier in the week.  How about a version that addresses a managed C# application.  Also, my biggest issue with this solution is that I don't want to distribute a version of NuGet.exe with my libraries.  Obviously the .NET Standard libraries don't need it to build a NuGet package, so it must be possible.

Comment: Also, it would appear that I need a license on NuGet packages before I can load them up to nuget.org.  A complete managed (C# or VB) example with themes, xaml controls and with all the metadata needed to upload to nuget.org would be very handy.